# Don't display if no records exist in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form to search names in mysql database

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

this is the search.php

```
<?php
        name = $_GET['name'];

        require_once("connect.php");

        $records = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM Userlists WHERE Name = '$name'");

        echo 
        "<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Description</th>            
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";

        if (mysqli_num_rows($records)== 0){
              echo "No data available for that name specified";
            }
            else {
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {

            $name = $row['Name'];
            $email = $row['Email'];
            $desc = $row['Desc']; 

            echo 
            "<tr>
            <td>".$name."</td>
            <td>".$email."</td>   
            <td>".$desc."</td>                                     
            </tr>";

           }

        }

        echo    
        "</tbody>
        </table>";
?>
```

so there is no problems when I search for a name that exists in database it displays correctly, but the problem comes when I search for a name that doesn't exist in database.. I want it to display only
`"No data available for that name specified"` for the output but I will also see empty table in the output like this ------------> [**IMAGE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FncdZ.jpg)..

so how can I get rid of the empty table for the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pu the if outside the table....

```
<?php
    name = $_GET['name'];

    require_once("connect.php");

    $records = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM Userlists WHERE Name = '$name'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($records)== 0){
       echo "No data available for that name specified";
    } else {


    echo 
    "<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Desc</th>            
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";


          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {

        $name = $row['Name'];
        $email = $row['Email'];
        $desc = $row['Desc']; 

        echo 
        "<tr>
        <td>".$name."</td>
        <td>".$email."</td>   
        <td>".$desc."</td>                                     
        </tr>";

       }



    echo    
    "</tbody>
    </table>";  
   }
?>
```

Comment: thanks, since most of the answers are helpful, I have just accepted the one who posted an answer first.

Answer (score 1):

change your if clause as below and remember to add `exit()` or `die()` function,this will end your `php` if there is no any data in database, and if there is any it will then start creating table for once and repeatedly fill up the table rows for given rows of data on database.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($records)== 0){
    echo "No data available for that name specified";
    exit();
} else {
    echo 
    "<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Desc</th>            
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {

        $name = $row['Name'];
        $email = $row['Email'];
        $desc = $row['Desc']; 

        echo 
        "<tr>
        <td>".$name."</td>
        <td>".$email."</td>   
        <td>".$desc."</td>                                     
        </tr>";

      }

    echo    
    "</tbody>
    </table>";
}
```

Comment: thanks also, I will add those. there were many answers and were helpful, I didn't know which one to accept.. so I just accepted the first one who posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `echo 
        "<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Desc</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";`

into the the if statement. This way it will only display the table when data is available!

Comment: thanks, i think it was the only thing I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $name = $_GET['name'];

        require_once("connect.php");

        $records = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM Userlists WHERE Name = '$name'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($records)== 0){
    echo "No data available for that name specified";
}
else {
    echo
    "<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Desc</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {

        $name = $row['Name'];
        $email = $row['Email'];
        $desc = $row['Desc'];

        echo
            "<tr>
            <td>" . $name . "</td>
            <td>" . $email . "</td>
            <td>" . $desc . "</td>
            </tr>";

    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
```

Try this one. But don't forget to escape $_GET['name'] like htmlspecialchars and real_escape_string

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to go for that to escape from mysql injections.